# two variables values in one variable is possible?

Tags: php

My code:

```
$url = "http://www.google.com/test";

$parseurl = parse_url($url);

$explode = explode('.', $parseurl['host']);

$arrayreverse = array_reverse($explode);

foreach(array_values($arrayreverse) as $keyvalue) {
    $result[] = $keyvalue;
}

$implode = implode('.', $result);
...
```

I'm interested to have values in one variable from $`implode` result and the result if isset the path from $`parseurl`... how can I do that ?

EDIT:

I want the values of `$implode + and(if isset $parseurl['path'])`; to be in 1 variable but I can't figure out how to unite them.

Comment: Explain your answer more clearly. What do you want to do? You want to check if the `$parseurl` is set? and show the result from implode? What you've done above is redundant.... you simply recreate the string

Comment: He's not recreating the string, he's reversing the components. The result will be `com.google.www`.

Comment: echo $implode + and(if isset $parseurl['path']);

Comment: But I don't understand the question, either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is ths what you want?

```
$newurl = $implode . (isset($parseurl['path']) ? $parseurl['path'] : '');
```

It uses the conditional operator to return either the path or an empty string, and concatenate that onto  `$implode`.

Comment: that code I write it but I never unite 2 variables in one... I still learning:), Happy new year!

Comment: You don't know the `.` operator to concatenate strings?